# Problems using subprocess.call() in Python 2.7.2 on Windows

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying the following and its failing with an error. I've tried to run it from Python shell/from a script/ on the windows console by invoking python on console. Nothing seems to work. Always the same error.

```
from subprocess import call
>>>pat = "d:\info2.txt"

>>> call(["type",pat])

>>>Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#56>", line 1, in <module>
    call(["type",pat])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 493, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 893, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

does anyone know what is wrong here.!!???

even the simple `call(["date"]]` without any arguements also fails with the same error.

I'm using :
Python 2.72 32bit version on a windows 7 machine.

Comment: what is `call` in your example? please include your imports? Assuming you mean the function from the `subprocess` package, I can't reproduce your error, since `call(["data"])` works perfectly fine on my system. What are your python version, os, and stuff like that?

Comment: Here are the details you asked for : Yes, call is the function in subprocess. I've made the necessary edits now above. hope the situation is clear now.

Comment: @David Zwicker: The DOS command `date` exists on Windows, it displays or sets the date.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Add `shell=True` to [call](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call):

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.call('dir', shell=True)
0
```

As you see, it gives as value the return code, not the output of `dir`. Also, it waits till the command completes, so doing

```
>>> subprocess.call('date', shell=True)
```

will wait for you to enter a new date.

**edit:**  If you want to capture the output, use `subprocess.check_output`. The DOS command `type` for example prints out the contents of a file. So, suppose that your file `info2.txt` contains your username, you would do:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> path = r'd:\info2.txt'
>>> output = subprocess.check_output(['type', path], shell=True)
>>> print output
Vinu
```

For all the ways to call external commands in Python, see this [comprehensive overview to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/92395/50065), for more about `subprocess` specifically, see [this article by Doug Hellmann](http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/subprocess/).

Comment: Thank you @BioGeek that was helpful. Its helps me solve the problem of the error, but doesn't help me with the main cause. All I wanted to do was **type a file out to the cmd console**.

Comment: What do you mean by _type a file out to the cmd console_? If you want to use the DOS command `type` to capture the contents of a file, see my edit. If you want something else, please clarify.

Comment: NO, I've got the solution now. THank for your help @BioGeek

Comment: +Vinu, so what was the solution?

Comment: @BioGeek while running in Python shell, subprocess.call('dir', shell=True) gives the output also along with return code.. am I missing something???

Comment: @DevC [That's not what I'm seeing.](http://i.imgur.com/0tAAQiM.png). Could you post a screenshot of ` subprocess.call('dir', shell=True)` also giving the output of the `dir` command?

Comment: `shell=true` should be avoided according to [subprocess' manual](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments). The correct solution should be @user1016274 's answer.

Answer (score 4):

The 'type' command doesn't run because it's an internal command - internal to the command interpreter/shell called CMD.EXE. You have to call "cmd.exe type filename" instead.
The exact code is:

```
call(['cmd','/C type abc.txt'])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
pat = "d:\info2.txt"
```

In Python and most other programming languages, `\` is an escape character, which is not included in a string unless doubled.  Either use a raw string or escape the escape character:

```
pat = "d:\\info2.txt"
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tried that too. Its not working either. I would like to draw your attention to : **call(["date"])** is also failing with the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Escape the `\` with `\\`:

```
pat = "d:\\info2.txt"
```

or use "raw" strings:

```
pat = r"d:\info2.txt"
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tried that too. Its not working either. I would like to draw your attention to : **call(["date"])** is also failing with the same error