# Run R script from python WINDOWS

Tags: python, windows, r

I made this code and it is working but only in Linux.

```
import subprocess as sub
sub.Popen([r"Rscript","diccionari.R"])
```

Where "diccionari.R" is the name of my script in R.
Error text message: System can't found the specific file.
[image]

Can somebody help me and do that it works on windows please?
Thank you.

Comment: Why is it not working, what is the exact error message you get? Right now we are just as unsure of what goes wrong as you are.

Comment: what error are you geting ?

Comment: reedited with the error I'm geting. But I don't understant why in linux it works if it's the same file name, directory, etc...

Comment: You have to give the full path to the .r script! (that would be my guess)

Comment: Check this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9531683/problems-using-subprocess-call-in-python-2-7-2-on-windows

Comment: I have checked it, and if I add shell=True to my script it opends my file but don't run the script (it only opens R console).

Comment: with shell=True, it works for me it displays the output of the Rscript. Also, with out shell=True, it worked for me if the path to RScript is given with double backward slashes in the path (C:\\My\\PATH\\RScript.R)

Comment: rags can you put the code your are using please? My is only opening R console.

Comment: My Try.py has ... sub.Popen([r"Rscript","D:\\Python34\\diccionari.R"]) and my diccionari.R has a<-1+2  ...  print(a) .... I am using python 3.4 and R 3.0.2

Comment: in my case it isn't working, but it may be my foult, so thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You should specify where `Rscript`is located i.e

```
import subprocess as sub    
cmd_line = [r"C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-3.6.0\\bin\\Rscript", "diccionari.R"]

sub.Popen(cmd_line)
```

watch for the `\\` characters

Answer (score 0):

You should probably try the slashes the other way around as how I said it earlier.

Using full path to the `.r` script (e.g. "`C:/myfolder/diccionari.R`") instead of just the script file, and using OS independent slashes.