# iPython equivalent of Unix "sh" command

Tags: python, shell, unix, ipython

Is there an iPython equivalent to executing the Unix `sh` command? I'd like to execute multiple iterations of a program via a shell file that has a set of lines such as:

```
%run python_file.py data_file1
%run python_file.py data_file2
.
.
.
%run python_file.py data_fileN
```

The python_file.py has sys module argv calls to allow command line inputs.

Comment: write a second pyhton script that executes them. Is that an option?

Comment: how can I write a program that outputs an executable command to the iPython shell?

Answer (score 1):

in the directory where you the `python_file.py` is located you create a python file called `run_python_file.py` (or somthing like that), it should contain

```
from subprocess import call
from sys import argv 

if len(argv) <= 1:
    print "Usage..."

for i in range(0,int(argv[1])): #n has to be defined somewhere!
    call(['python','python_file.py','data_file'+str(i)])
```

In your iPython shell you navigate to the folder where `python_file.py` is located and then call

```
%run run_python_file.py 5
```

if you want to run it with datafiles from 0 to 4

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick response! I really like the idea to use the "call" method from subprocess, but when I run the code I'm getting a "WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified". Any ideas for a work around?

Comment: I think this might interest you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9531683/problems-using-subprocess-call-in-python-2-7-2-on-windows

Comment: Nice, thanks! When I add the parameter "shell=True" it solves the WindowsError issue, but I'm not getting the call output to execute in the command line. I tried added 'cmd' as recommended in that link, but it's just crashing Canopy.

Comment: I just search for completely different stuff to make a linux command run in windows from within geany editor. Answer is also completely irrelevant. But finally this post gave me an idea for a different approach which solved my problem. Hurray. Upvote for your answer.