# How do I set the size of a JButton?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton, border-layout

The button takes up the whole screen, and I try using `setSize()` but that doesn't appear to be doing anything. Here's my code so far:

```
JButton start = new JButton("PLAY");
start.setSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
myFrame.add(start);
```

Comment: have you tried calling myFrame.pack();?

Comment: No I have not, what does it do?

Comment: it apllies the specified layout to the componenets http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9531683/problems-using-subprocess-call-in-python-2-7-2-on-windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `JFrame` has `BorderLayout` with `CENTER` alignment. Thats why single component will takes full screen. So add a suitable Layout Manager to `JFrame`.

For details, go through, [How to Use Various Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/layoutlist.html).

Comment: thank you! I'll accept your answer whenever it will alow me to. (11-ish minutes).

Comment: +1, for suggesting to use layout managers. -1 for suggestion a null layout!!! There is absolutely no reason to use a null layout in this case and the OP will not learn how to use Swing the way it was designed to be used.

Comment: @camickr, I used null layout as an example to view the Dimension size, not suggest to used it.

Answer (score 1):

you can try using `GridBagLayout` to set it's size within a `Container`.

[image: img]
    import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
    import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
    import java.awt.Insets;
    import javax.swing.JButton;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;

```
public class test extends JPanel{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    JButton b1, b2, b3, b4, b5;
    GridBagConstraints g = new GridBagConstraints();
    public test() {
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        g.insets = new Insets(1, 1, 1, 1);
        b1 = new JButton("Button 1");
        g.gridx = 0;
        g.gridy = 6;
        g.gridwidth = 2;
        g.gridheight = 1;
        g.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        g.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
        add(b1, g);
        b2 = new JButton("Button 2");
        g.gridx = 0;
        g.gridy = 0;
        g.gridwidth = 3;
        g.gridheight = 1;
        g.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        g.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
        add(b2, g);
        b3 = new JButton("Button 3");
        g.gridx = 2;
        g.gridy = 2;
        g.gridwidth = 1;
        g.gridheight = 1;
        g.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        g.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
        add(b3, g);
        b4 = new JButton("Button 4");
        g.gridx = 6;
        g.gridy = 0;
        g.gridheight = 3;
        g.gridwidth = 1;
        g.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        g.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
        add(b4, g);
        b5 = new JButton("Button 5");
        g.gridx = 1;
        g.gridy = 3;
        g.gridheight = 1;
        g.gridwidth = 2;
        g.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        g.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
        add(b5, g);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    test t = new test();
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("test");
    frame.setSize(500, 500);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.add(t);
    }
}
```