# subprocess.py error: Ninja not building from source on Windows 8

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess, ninja

I tried building Ninja from source. I did:

```
$ git clone git://github.com/martine/ninja.git && cd ninja
$ git checkout release
```

Then in a Visual Studio command line I ran `configure.py` with Python:

```
$ C:\Python27\python.exe configure.py --bootstrap
```

But here I get the following error:

```
C:\ninja>C:\Python27\python.exe configure.py --bootstrap
bootstrapping ninja...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "configure.py", line 320, in <module>
    if platform.msvc_needs_fs():
  File "configure.py", line 84, in msvc_needs_fs
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\subprocess.py", line 390, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\subprocess.py", line 640, in _execute_chi
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

After reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9532379/) answer, I added `shell=True` to all `call()` and `check_call()` occurrences in `configure.py`. But that still doesn't help.

Any ideas what to do?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [code in question](https://github.com/ninja-build/ninja/blob/d6eb8baf8130ab93140395dceca363774092135d/configure.py#L81-L86), it's trying to run `cl`, which is part of Microsoft Visual C++.

Do you have MSVC installed and in your `PATH`? I.e. does just running `cl` on the command line work?

Comment: Just running `cl` on command line doesn't work, although I have Microsoft Visual C++ installed.

Comment: So that likely means it's not on the PATH. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f2ccy3wt.aspx :)

Comment: I scoured my entire C:\ drive but couldn't find the path to Microsoft Visual C++. However, I do see it in the list of installed applications (in Programs and Features in Control Panel).